# Custom attribute not passed into ID_TOKEN created by AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-userpools

I am not able to get **custom attribute in ID_TOKEN** returned from AWS Cognito after successful user login.

Steps I tried :

1.Created user pool
2.Created app client and checked the custom attribute(*customattrib1,customattrib2*)

User Pool screen :

[image]

Check custom attribute in app client config

[image]

3.Created user using admin-create-user api

Below image shows the value for user attributes:

[image]

4.Signed in user using aws-cognito-auth.js in client app.The ID token returned do not contain the custom attribute.

**ID_TOKEN**

```
{
  "at_hash": "PKfjYDaiEty5mUOyJZlPQA",
  "sub": "639d5016-2bd3-4c6f-b82d-21ae38071b09",
  "email_verified": true,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ap-south-1_XXXXXXX",
  "phone_number_verified": true,
  "cognito:username": "testuser",
  "aud": "XYXYXYXYX",
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": 1549349674,
  "phone_number": "##########",
  "exp": 1549353274,
  "iat": 1549349674,
  "email": "testuser@somedomain.com"
}
```

I have already checked links below, which had some info regarding this issue, but nothing helped so far.

[Adding Cognito custom attributes post pool creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087087/adding-cognito-custom-attributes-post-pool-creation)

[Cognito User Pool custom attributes do not show up in the ID token if user pool is configured with a SAML identity provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763113/cognito-user-pool-custom-attributes-do-not-show-up-in-the-id-token-if-user-pool)

[Cognito User Pool custom attributes do not show up in the ID token if user pool is configured with a SAML identity provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763113/cognito-user-pool-custom-attributes-do-not-show-up-in-the-id-token-if-user-pool)

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/a07dwg/cognito_add_custom_attribute_to_jwt_token/

Please help me figure out if I am missing something..

Comment: Custom attributes will only appear if they are assigned a value. Did you add value in the custom attributes you created?

Comment: @AtharKhan Yes,the values were provided while creating user, I have updated question description to add the image showing value of user attributes.

Comment: and you are sure that app client id used for token generation is the one where you've assigned the readable/writable permissions?

Comment: @AtharKhan Yes, there is only one app client and the same I have marked the attribute and pasted the screen print of the same.

Answer (score 63):

- In your Cognito user pool go to General Settings -> App Clients, then for each app client click on `Show Details`, then `Set attribute read and write permissions`. Check the checkbox next to your attribute name under `Readable Attributes`.
- In your Cognito user pool go to App client settings -> Allowed OAuth Scopes and enable `profile` scope.

Comment: One additional add on: make sure if you are using the hosted ui url that the url contains profile as part of the scope parameter: IE &scope=email%20openid+profile . Having this in the app client settings isn't sufficient, it must be included in the hosted UI request params as well, or it will not return them as part of the jwt payload.

Comment: If somebody is looking for cdk solution then cognito.UserPoolClient has property readAttributes. Create it like `(new cognito.ClientAttributes()).withCustomAttributes("custom:something")`, there is a bug that withCustomAttributes creates a new object instead of appending to its own.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same trouble and your question came up when I was searching for a solution.

My custom attributes started to appear in ID token when I enabled *profile* scope in 'App client settings'. (available at: AWS console-> 'User pools'-> click your pool -> 'App client settings' -> 'Allowed OAuth Scopes')

(BTW: I was misled by this sentence from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html): "The *openid* scope returns all user attributes in the ID token that are readable by the client". In my case *openid* scope was not enough.)

Comment: The updated the documentation. Now it reads: "The `profile` scope grants access to all user attributes that are readable by the client. This scope can only be requested with the `openid` scope."

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here that is using the Amplify SDK like the OP - Copy and Paste calls out an important point that your client ALSO needs to explicitly ask for the scope.

In my case we I am using Angular.  After adding "profile" to the User Pool "Allowed OAuth Scopes" - you also need to specify it in your client configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was getting my token (after authenticating with the Amplify js library) from:

```
Auth.currentSession().then(u => u.getAccessToken().getJwtToken())
```

Instead of:

```
Auth.currentSession().then(u => u.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
```

After changing it worked fine! Hope it helps!