# AWS Cognito Custom attribute is missing from ID token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a cognito userpool with a custom attribute. Attribute is mutable and the type is Boolean. But it is missing from the ID token

I tried following things

- In App client explicitly  made the attribute readable / writable
- Unticked all the attributes to make them all readable / writable
- Enabled OAuth scopes - Profile

None of them worked. How do I add custom attributes to the ID token?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom attribute not passed into ID\_TOKEN created by AWS Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530776/custom-attribute-not-passed-into-id-token-created-by-aws-cognito)

Comment: @yudhiesh Nope tried them all.. did nt work

Comment: Have you tried asking AWS Support?

Comment: @yudhiesh AWS support is very slow, and really hard to find information from their docs.. hence did not go to their support.. Instead I came to SO. But went through all of the similar threads in their support forums, github issues etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a fix for this

In my case, I did not receive the attribute as it did not contain any value. The attribute will only be included in the token only if it contains a value

***Important points found on research:***

- Make sure your attribute is readable. You can do this by visiting App clients -> Show details -> Set attribute read and write permissions (Insignificant link in the bottom.) -> tick your attribute that you want to be included in the token
- If you are adding the attribute to an existing user pool, then you can not make it required.

Comment: Thank you! Finding App Clients -> Show Details -> Set Attribute read/write was killing me!